# Copy table between databases

Tags: postgresql

```
Select * into exp.dbo.client from db.dbo.client
```

I'm trying to copy a table from one database to another in postgres and it's showing me that the references between the databases aren't implemented.
And if there an easier way to copy the whole database instead of table by table, please tell me.

Comment: I'd suggest pd_dump  and restore if this is a once-in--a-while operation.

Comment: No you cannot do database.schema.table queries. To get a complete answer you will need to provide the Postgres versions involved. Also a more complete description of what you want to achieve. In meantime you can use [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) and [pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html) to transfer databases.

Comment: I'm actually trying to create a data warehouse and in or to apply the ETL process, I need to extract the data, so I thought about copying it in a temp database and delete the data I don't need.Beside in the data warehouse this operation needs to be done daily so I don't think pg_dump and pg_restore are the best way to do it

Comment: If the two databases are on the same server, it's better to use schemas in a single database instead. If those are different servers use a foreign data wrapper

Comment: `db.dbo.client` BTW: there are no three-level identifiers in (postgres) SQL. dbo is a microsoft invention.

Answer (score 0):

After executing "create extension dblink" in the database you can after excute this query to copy tableOne from database to tableTwo, without creating it before

```
create table tableTwo
as 
select * 
from dblink('host=localhost
            user=username 
            password=password
            dbname=current_database',
           'select * from tableOne') as linkable( var1 type1, var2 type2,var3 type3,... )
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow—and thank you for your contribution. Would you mind editing your answer to include some additional explanation? Are there tradeoffs to this approach? What variables need to be modified? Are there cases where this wouldn't work?

Comment: I just did it, I don't know if it's clearenough though

Answer (score 0):

To clone the whole database on the same server:

```
CREATE DATABASE "db_new" WITH TEMPLATE "db_old" OWNER owner1
```